# What is the minimum number of parts required to split the sequence S to in order to obtain sequence T?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, subsequences, c++

Suppose a person has a sequence (S) consisting of integer numbers and would like to split the sequence into a
number (possibly one) of continuous parts. For each part independently, I then choose any integer
value and removes all occurrences of this value in the corresponding part (note that there could be
no such occurrences). After that, the person will combine all parts in the same order to achieve a new
sequence (T). 
 How to find out the minimum number of parts needed to split the sequence in order to achieve this goal .

 let n = size of sequence S and m = size of sequence T

---

- **Constraints**: 
  1 <= n,m <= 2000

---

- **Input Format:** n m 
   Sequence S  
   Sequence T
- **Output Format:** if it is not possible to transform S into T output -1 
   otherwise, output min number of parts required.
- **Sample Input and Output**:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 4 2 4 2 7 2 4 7 | 1 |
| 7 2 4 7 1 4 1 7 1 4 7 | 3 |
| 3 2 7 4 2 4 7 | -1 |

---

**My Attempt:**
I did not understand how Sequence S={4,2,7,2} can be transformed to T = {4,7}. If I followed this procedure by splitting a sequence into parts such as {4} {2} {7} {2} and then iterate from 1st index and then the 2nd index until the end, and if I encounter the same value I delete all of its occurrences. When I do this, I get  the sequence {4,2,7} and minpart is just 1.

And, for the sequence {4,7,1,4,1,7,1}, I am able to get {4,7,1} and minparts are 3.

But I do not understand, how both of these sequences: S = {4,2,7,2} and S = {4,7,1,4,1,7,1} can be transformed to the sequence T = {4,7}?

Comment: Can you tell us where you encountered this task?

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the sequence $T = \{4,7\}$ from $S = \{4,2,7,2\}$, you can take the entire set S as a minipart and remove $2$ from it. Therefore, there is just *one* minipart.
2. To get the sequence $T = \{4,7\}$ from $S = \{4,7,1,4,1,7,1\}$, you can take *three* minimarts as follows:

   - $P1 = \{4\}$
   - $P2 = \{7\}$
   - $P3 = \{1,4,1,7,1\}$

   Now, remove $4$ from $P1$, remove $7$ from $P2$, and remove $1$ from $P3$. You will get the sequence $T = \{4,7\}$.

Comment: There is a simple Dynamic Programming algorithm for this problem. You can first think on that by yourself and then ask if you are facing any difficulties.

Comment: But how can I decide the length of each minpart??

Comment: @Powerfulblaster You are asking about the algorithm or you have some doubt in the above explanation of sample inputs/outputs.

Comment: Why you did not take the 1st one also as a minpart? so you have {4} {7} {1} {4,1,7,1}?? Or  The numbers deleted from each minpart should be different?

Comment: @Powerfulblaster The numbers deleted from each minipart could be the same.

Comment: @Powerfulblaster We want to minimize the number of miniparts. In this case: {4} {7} {1} {4,1,7,1}, the number of miniparts are four. This is not the minimum. The minimum is three as shown in the answer.

Comment: but what if we have Sequence {8,1,4,5,1,7,1}. What will be the minparts in this case??

Comment: @Powerfulblaster For T = {4,7}, the minimum number of miniparts are four, i.e., {8} {1} {4,5} {1,7,1}.

Comment: Is it a must to remove only one number from each partition, what if we have Sequence {4,7,3,6,8} How many partitions will be there??

Comment: @Powerfulblaster You can not remove more than one type of number from any partition. And it is always better to remove a number from a partition rather than not removing any number because you want to minimize the number of partitions. And, for the sequence {4,7,3,6,8} there would be three partitions: {4,7,3} {6} {8}

Comment: I can think of an $O(n^2m)$-time DP algorithm for this, which in the end is fairly simple, but I wouldn't say that it's obvious that it can be solved this quickly. Handling each subproblem in $O(n)$ time requires an insight about how to efficiently generate all and only the valid (suffix of prefix of S, value to delete) pairs.